# How to tell Finder to select/reveal multiple files in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, finder

Using the following code:

```
tell application "Finder" to reveal every item of theFiles
```

Works when theFiles contains a single file, but when it contains multiple files, I get:

```
error "Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

What am I doing wrong? I simply want to highlight a list of files in Finder.

Comment: where are thefiles being defined ?

Comment: They start as posix paths and get converted to aliases.

Comment: can I see the code that makes the alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
tell application "Finder" to reveal theFiles
```

An example I was looking at shows "... reveal every item of ...". I'm not sure if they're in error or something changed with AS.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work fine

```
  tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to entire contents of folder of (choose folder)
    reveal every item of theFiles
  end tell
```

Comment: Hmm. Does "entire contents of folder" return a list of aliases?

Comment: @Jeremy Cantrell did this help ?